# Showing a zoomable, scrollable image on Apple Watch

Tags: api, maps, watchkit, implementation, apple-watch

I'm trying to make an Apple Watch app (extension) which shows a map in a way similar to Apple's Maps app. I want to be able to show a portion of the map, and then be able to use the digital crown to zoom and gestures to scroll.

I think this should be possible with Watch OS2, but I haven't figured out which APIs to use.

Is this possible on the platform at present?

Update: I don't think I can use WKInterfaceMap since I want to generate my own map, not use an existing one.

Answer (score 1):

Inside Watch OS2  API only WKInterfacePicker has access of Digit Crown
So We can't use Digit Crown For WKInterfaceMap Directly but we can use it by using  WKInterfacePicker

- Put WKInterfaceMap and WKInterfacePicker inside Group
- Set  WKInterfacePicker size width fixed = 2 height fixed = 2
  (We can not set size to  zero)

[image]

- NOTE : Don't hide WKInterfacePicker, Sometime, It resign focus because of hidden .
- Add below code for Picker Controller

  code

  ```
  class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {
      @IBOutlet var mapView : WKInterfaceMap!
      @IBOutlet var tempPicker:WKInterfacePicker!

      var zoomArray:[Double] = [1.0,0.98,0.96,0.94,0.92,0.90,0.88,0.86,0.84,0.82,0.80,0.78,0.76,0.74,0.72,0.70,0.68,0.66,0.64,0.62,0.60,0.58,0.56,0.54,0.52,0.50,0.48,0.46,0.44,0.42,0.40,0.38,0.36,0.34,0.32,0.30,0.28,0.26,0.24,0.22,0.20,0.18,0.16,0.14,0.12,0.10,0.09,0.08,0.07,0.06,0.05,0.04,0.03,0.02,0.01,0.009,0.008,0.007,0.006,0.005,0.004,0.003,0.002,0.001]

      override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
          super.awakeWithContext(context)
          let pickerItems: [WKPickerItem] = zoomArray.map {
                           let pickerItem = WKPickerItem()
                           pickerItem.caption = String($0)
                           pickerItem.title = String($0)
                           return pickerItem
           }

           self.tempPicker.setItems(pickerItems)
           self.tempPicker.setSelectedItemIndex(25)

           let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(zoomArray[25], zoomArray[25])
           let lc = watchDelegate.locationModel.myLocation ?? CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)//watchDelegate.locationModel.myLocation is current user Location
           let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(lc, span)
           self.mapView.setRegion(region)
      }

      @IBAction func pickerChanged(value: Int) {

          let lc = watchDelegate.locationModel.myLocation ?? CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)
          let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(zoomArray[value], zoomArray[value])
          let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(lc,
                                           span)
          self.mapView.setRegion(region)

          self.tempPicker.focus()
      }
  }
  ```

- Connect  @IBAction and IBOutlet to WKInterfacePicker and WKInterfaceMap